# if i run method in doinbackgroundand when it is running i am click any button then i got error...how to solve?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

i want to display all sms ..so i was run loadIntialMessage() to display 20 sms..

on this method i will run thread background to display next sms..
This is AsyncTask class which run on loadIntialmessage() method's list scroll method..

```
    public void loadInitialMessages() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "date", "body",
            "address", "type", "read" };
    String orderby;
    Log.d(TAG, "sory index" + sort_index);
    // sort_index =1;
    if (sort_index == 0) {
        orderby = "date DESC";
    } else {
        orderby = "date ASC";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < ((IdSMS.size() > NO_OF_SMS_TO_LOAD) ? NO_OF_SMS_TO_LOAD
            : IdSMS.size()); i++) {

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(SMS_URI_ALL),
                columns, " _id =" + IdSMS.get(i), null, null);
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String contactname = getContactDisplayNameByNumber((c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))));
            // Log.d(TAG, "contact number without replace space" +
            // contactname);
            if (contactname.contains(" ")) {
                contactname.replace(" ", "");
                // Log.d(TAG, "contact number  replace space" +
                // contactname);
            }
            if (!NumberListContact.contains(contactname)) {

                NumberListContact.add(contactname);
                IdSMS.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"))
                        .toString());
                ThreadSMS.add(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id")).toString());
                SMSDate.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"))
                        .toString());
                MessageList.add(c
                        .getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                        .toString());
                NumberList.add(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                SMSType.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"))
                        .toString());
                SMSRead.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read"))
                        .toString());
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "read and unread"
                                + c.getString(
                                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read"))
                                        .toString());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Counter Value " + counter);
            Log.d(TAG,
                    " thread_Id "
                            + c.getString(
                                    c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id"))
                                    .toString());

            counter++;
        }
        c.close();
    }

    // refreshAdapter();
    inboxAdaptor = new inboxAdaptor(getApplicationContext(), IdSMS,
            ThreadSMS, NumberListContact, NumberList, MessageList, SMSDate,
            SMSType, SMSRead);

    lvmsg.setAdapter(inboxAdaptor);

    inboxAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lvmsg.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (MessageList.size()
                    - (int) (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) <= 1) {
                Log.d("onScroll", " firstVisibleItem " + firstVisibleItem);
                Log.d("onScroll", " visibleItemCount " + visibleItemCount);
                Log.d("onScroll", " totalItemCount " + totalItemCount);

                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Adding more data to listview ---------------------->>");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        LoadNewMessage myTask = new LoadNewMessage(
                                MainActivity.this);
                        myTask.execute();
                    }
                });
                // if(!isLoadingNewMessages){
                // mLoadNewMessage.post(new Runnable() {
                //
                // @Override
                // public void run() {
                // // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // isLoadingNewMessages=true;
                // addToListview();
                //
                // }
                // });
                // }

            }
        }
    });

}

class LoadNewMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    ProgressDialog pd;
    Context context;

    public LoadNewMessage(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            addToListview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void... params) {

        inboxAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }

}
```

`

In addToListview() i was display next sms..

```
public void addToListview() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id", "date", "body",
            "address", "type", "read" };
    String orderby = "date DESC limit 10";
    if (sort_index == 1) {
        orderby = "date ASC";
    } else {
        orderby = "date DESC";
    }
    // Log.d(TAG, " Adding new values Counter "+counter);

    for (int i = 0; i < (((IdSMS.size() - counter) > NO_OF_SMS_TO_LOAD) ? NO_OF_SMS_TO_LOAD
            : (IdSMS.size() - counter)); i++) {

        Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(SMS_URI_ALL),
                columns, " _id =" + IdSMS.get(counter), null, null);
        // Log.d(TAG, " Adding new values cursor count "+c.getCount());
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String contactname = getContactDisplayNameByNumber((c
                    .getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"))));

            if (!NumberListContact.contains(contactname)) {

                NumberListContact.add(contactname);
                IdSMS.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"))
                        .toString());
                ThreadSMS.add(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id")).toString());
                SMSDate.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"))
                        .toString());
                MessageList.add(c
                        .getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"))
                        .toString());
                NumberList.add(c.getString(
                        c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                SMSType.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"))
                        .toString());
                SMSRead.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("read"))
                        .toString());
            }

        }
        c.close();
        counter++;
    }

    isLoadingNewMessages = false;
    // refreshAdapter();
}
```

but when i click any other button when message is load i got error..

```
   03-15 13:01:35.334: W/System.err(283): java.lang.NullPointerException
   03-15 13:01:35.334: W/System.err(283):   at com.example.smsmanager.MainActivity.addToListview(MainActivity.java:325)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at com.example.smsmanager.MainActivity$LoadNewMessage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:139)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at com.example.smsmanager.MainActivity$LoadNewMessage.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
   03-15 13:01:35.344: W/System.err(283):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Comment: post your code MainActivity.addToListview

Comment: post some code so that we can check.

Comment: Its a code error ,so post your code

Comment: i am edited my code...plz do reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my guess. Cannot be very specific unless you post the codes:

In the doInBackground method, it calls MainActivity.addToListview method, which modifies UI and some object isn't ready yet. The null object may depend on your async task finishing or you forgot to set it up?

Comment: i am displaying 20 sms by loadInitialmessage() then on this method i will runUIthread on scroll of listview to display next sms..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess: You are trying to update the UI from the AsyncTask which is not on the UI thread. What you have to do is send a message to a Handler and have the Handler update the UI.

Add this to your class variables:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
```

*Note: you can send all sorts of data through the `Message` object or with class variables*.

Add this to your doInBackground() function:

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Update your UI with a function added to your class like this:

```
private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // Do something to the UI here.
    }
};
```